# How concatenate 2 Numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 Numpy array `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` with shape of `(10,)   (10, 6)`  and I would like to concat the first one with the second. The numpy array provided below,

```
r1 
['467c8100-7f13-4244-81ee-5e2a0f8218a8',
 '71a4b5b2-80d6-4c12-912f-fc71be8d923e',
 '7a3e0168-e47d-4203-98f2-a54a46c62ae0',
 '7dfd43e7-ced1-435f-a0f9-80cfd00ae246',
 '85dbc70e-c773-43ee-b434-8f458d295d10',
 'a56b2bc3-4a81-469e-bc5f-b3aaa520db05',
 'a9e8996f-ff35-4bfb-bbd9-ede5ffecd4d8',
 'c3037410-0c2e-40f8-a844-ac0664a05783',
 'c5618563-10c0-425b-a11b-2fcf931f0ff7',
 'f65e6cea-892e-4335-8e86-bf7f083b5f53'] 

r2 
[[1.55000000e+02, 5.74151515e-01, 1.55000000e+02, 5.74151515e-01, 3.49000000e+02, 1.88383585e+00],
 [5.00000000e+00, 1.91871554e-01, 1.03000000e+02, 1.22893828e+00, 2.95000000e+02, 3.21148368e+00],
 [7.10000000e+01, 1.15231270e-01, 2.42000000e+02, 5.78527276e-01, 4.09000000e+02, 2.67915246e+00],
 [3.60000000e+01, 7.10066720e-01, 2.42000000e+02, 1.80213634e+00, 4.12000000e+02, 4.16314391e+00],
 [1.15000000e+02, 1.05120284e+00, 1.30000000e+02, 1.71697773e+00, 2.53000000e+02, 2.73640301e+00],
 [4.70000000e+01, 2.19434656e-01, 3.23000000e+02, 4.84093786e+00, 5.75000000e+02, 7.00530186e+00],
 [5.50000000e+01, 1.22614463e+00, 1.04000000e+02, 1.55392099e+00, 4.34000000e+02, 4.13661261e+00],
 [3.90000000e+01, 3.34816889e-02, 1.10000000e+02, 2.54431753e-01, 2.76000000e+02, 1.52322736e+00],
 [3.43000000e+02, 2.93550948e+00, 5.84000000e+02, 5.27968165e+00, 7.45000000e+02, 7.57657633e+00],
 [1.66000000e+02, 1.01436635e+00, 2.63000000e+02, 2.69197514e+00, 8.13000000e+02, 7.96477735e+00]]
```

I tried to concatenate with the command `np.concatenate((r1, r2))`, it returns with the message of `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions` which I don't understand. Because, the `r1` can possibly concat with the `r2` and can form a whole new array and make a new array of `10 x 7` as result.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: How should the result array look like?

Comment: `10 x 7` dimensions and each element of the `r1` with precede rows in the numpy array, LIKE: 

`[  '467c8100-7f13-4244-81ee-5e2a0f8218a8', 1.55000000e+02   5.74151515e-01   1.55000000e+02   5.74151515e-01 3.49000000e+02   1.88383585e+00]`

Comment: Quick question - are you going to *keep* concatenating columns to the result, in a loop? If so, you should try to restructure your program so you don't need to do that. It's one of the least efficient ways you could possibly work with NumPy arrays, since you need to recopy all the data every time.

Comment: This is all I have and I expressed the way I would like to concatenate from here. Each row should be like `[ '467c8100-7f13-4244-81ee-5e2a0f8218a8', 1.55000000e+02 5.74151515e-01 1.55000000e+02 5.74151515e-01 3.49000000e+02 1.88383585e+00]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) `r1` to make it two-dimensional and specify the `axis` along which the arrays should be joined:

```py
import numpy as np

r1 = np.ones((10,))
r2 = np.zeros((10, 6))
np.concatenate((r1.reshape(10, 1), r2), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Numpy offers an easy way to concatenate along the second axis.

```
np.c_[r2,r1]
```

Answer (score 1):

These 2 array have a dtype and shape mismatch:

```
In [174]: r1.shape
Out[174]: (10,)
In [175]: r1.dtype
Out[175]: dtype('<U36')

In [177]: r2.shape
Out[177]: (10, 6)
In [178]: r2.dtype
Out[178]: dtype('float64')
```

If you add a dimension to `r1`, so it is now (10,1), you can concatenate on axis=1.  But note the dtype - the floats have been turned into strings:

```
In [181]: r12 =np.concatenate((r1[:,None], r2), axis=1)
In [182]: r12.shape
Out[182]: (10, 7)
In [183]: r12.dtype
Out[183]: dtype('<U36')
In [184]: r12[0,:]
Out[184]: 
array(['467c8100-7f13-4244-81ee-5e2a0f8218a8', '155.0', '0.574151515',
       '155.0', '0.574151515', '349.0', '1.88383585'], 
      dtype='<U36')
```

A way to mix string and floats is with structured array, for example:

```
In [185]: res=np.zeros((10,),dtype='U36,(6)f')
In [186]: res.dtype
Out[186]: dtype([('f0', '<U36'), ('f1', '<f4', (6,))])
In [187]: res['f0']=r1
In [188]: res['f1']=r2
In [192]: res.shape
Out[192]: (10,)
In [193]: res[0]
Out[193]: ('467c8100-7f13-4244-81ee-5e2a0f8218a8', [ 155.        ,    0.57415152,  155.        ,    0.57415152,  349.        ,    1.88383579])
```

We could also make a (10,7) array with dtype=object.  But most array operations won't work with such a mix of strings and floats.  And the ones that work are slower.

Why do you want to concatenate these arrays?  What do you intend to do with the result?  That `dtype` mismatch is more serious than the shape mismatch.